# Update IMPORTRANGE formula on column change in the source sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

When in the source sheet, a column is moved, the "IMPORTRANGE" formula does not update accordingly.
Example- Suppose in my source sheet, I have a column with header named "Value" in column "B".

[image]

And I use the following formula in destination sheet.

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP($A2:$A, IMPORTRANGE(source_sheet_id, "source!$A$2:A"), IMPORTRANGE(source_sheet_id, "source!$B$2:B"), , 0, 1))
```

Now, in source sheet, if I move the "Value" column from "B" to "C", I want the above formula to update accordingly as follows-

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP($A2:$A, IMPORTRANGE(source_sheet_id, "source!$A$2:A"), IMPORTRANGE(source_sheet_id, "source!$C$2:C"), , 0, 1))
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One approach is to dynamically search for the column(in source sheet) with header **`Value`**. So now moving this specific column would not break this formula:*

```js
=let(Σ,source_sheet_id,
     arrayformula(xlookup(A2:A,importrange(Σ,"source!A2:A"),choosecols(importrange(Σ,"source!A2:"&rows(importrange(Σ,"source!A:A"))),xmatch("Value",importrange(Σ,"source!1:1"))),)))
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the same result using `Query` function?

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOW(),XLOOKUP(A2:A,IMPORTRANGE(source_sheet_id,"source!A2:A"),IMPORTRANGE(source_sheet_id,"source!C2:C"),)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I found is using **named ranges**. Steps are as follows-

- In the source sheet, create a *named range* for the column containing the data. For example, select the "Value" column (in "B") and go to `Data` > `Named ranges` > Give it a name like "Values".
- Update the `IMPORTRANGE` formula in the destination sheet to use the created *named range* instead of just the cell reference.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP($A2:$A, IMPORTRANGE(source_sheet_id, "source!$A$2:A"), INDIRECT("'source_sheet_id'!Values"), , 0, 1))
```